# Jquery platform conflict

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

The scripts bellow are called to facilitate a slideshow

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/s3Slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider1').s3Slider({
            timeOut: 8000 
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I call add the one bellow below nothing works again

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css"          media="screen" />
```

How do I stop the conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling jQuery twice. Don't do that.

In the first:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In the second:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```